# Using environment variables in lpCurrentDirectory argument to CreateProcess function

Tags: windows, winapi

I am needing to launch an executable whose working directory is set using an environment variable. For example, I would need to do something like:

```
CreateProcess(exe, args, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, TEXT("%CUSTOM_DIR%"), &si, &pi);
```

However, this consistently returns false with `ERROR_DIRECTORY` (267) set as the last error. I have verified that the `CUSTOM_DIR` environment variable is indeed set with the code:

```
auto environment = GetEnvironmentStrings();
auto env = environment;
while (*env)
{
    printf("%ls\n", env);
    env += wcslen(env) + 1;
}
FreeEnvironmentStrings(environment);
```

As well as:

```
TCHAR szVal[1024];
GetEnvironmentVariable(TEXT("CUSTOM_DIR"), szVal, 1024);
printf("%ls\n", szVal);
```

After searching for a bit on MSDN as well as SO, I haven't been able to find anything much related to this question. The only way I can get it done now is the terrible solution of parsing the string and doing the substitution myself (yuk!).

Comment: You do need to read the question to answer the question. I'm passing an environment variable name to `lpCurrentDirectory` not `lpEnvironment`... If `CreateProcess` (or other function) won't do the substitution for me, that's cool, I can do it myself (reluctantly). Your response does not address the question, though...

Comment: Yes, I do need to read the question!! Oops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system will not expand environment variables for you in that context. You have to do it yourself before calling CreateProcess.

Comment: That's disappointing. At least I found the [ExpandEnvironmentStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724265(v=vs.85).aspx) function.